# c# how to show image in picturebox if file format is .jpg

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax-error, picturebox, openfiledialog

i have a problem. i want to load image file or rar/zip to my WPF. when i click button on my WPF to open file dialog, i got some errors.

this is my code to open file dialog.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        op.Title = "Select a File";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                    "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                    "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png"+
                    "Zip Files|*.zip;*.rar";

        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(op.FileName);
                _path = op.FileName;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

my question is how to show image if file format is .jpg / .png, and show rar icon or any icon if file format is .rar / .zip in picturebox.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the content of your question?!

Comment: This smells like WinForms.

Comment: sorry. my bad. i have fix the title.

Comment: what is error message ? and how do u define op object ?

Comment: OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

Comment: How is a PictureBox going to open a zip file?  That's not an image.

Comment: Are you trying to show the file icon in the same way that Windows Explorer does?

Comment: i mean, if image file, show the image, if rar / zip, show icon / png / or similar.

Comment: Please be more specific and tell us exactly what type of error you are getting (including the stack-trace if possible). Also make sure to include what you've already tried and that the code is formatted properly.

Comment: got messegebox that show out of memory when i select rar file.

Comment: how to disable picturebox if the file is rar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İf I don't understand wrong, the solution for your question is like this code below;

Firstly, you should choose a general picture to show in the picturebox when a **zip** or **rar** file is chosen by user. Then place the chosen picture (*ex: rar.jpg*) under the app's **bin\debug** folder.

Then, use the codes below;

```
        try
        {

            op.Title = "Select a File";
            op.Filter = "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff|"
   + "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
   + "Zip Files|*.zip;*.rar";

            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string x = op.FileName.ToString();
                char[] ayrac = { '.' };
                string[] kelimeler = x.Split(ayrac);
                string y = kelimeler[1].ToString();

                if (y != "zip" && y != "rar")
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(op.FileName);
                    _path = op.FileName;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                }
                else
                {
                    //How to get picture: The best way is to put the subfolder under the app's bin\debug\,thus you can simply coding:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"rar.jpg", true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I hope, the code is ok for your question.

Comment: No problem. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to get the file icon. To do that use [`ExtractAssociatedIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
pictureBox1.Image = icon.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: i mean, if image file, show the image that i select, if rar / zip, show icon / png / or similar on picturebox.

Comment: Then use the code I've shown in conjunction with yours. Check the file extension and device which code to use.

Comment: i have solve it. the problem is in 'op.Filter'. now i have another problem. when i open .rar file, messegebox show 'out of memory'. any solution ?

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: soo, any solution ?

Comment: how to disable picturebox if the file is rar ?

Comment: You can't just keep asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you want is a simple if-statement that checks the file-ending, like this:

```
using System.IO;

if (Path.GetExtension(op.FileName).EndsWith("rar")
    || Path.GetExtension(op.FileName).EndsWith("zip"))
{
    // File has rar or zip extension
    // Load default image from resources
} 
else
{
    // Load provided image
}
```

and you may even add `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to the `EndsWith`-call if you want to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: yeah. i want a simple if-statement, but i'm new here. btw, ty for ur answer. i appreciate that.